# Accessing a dictionary using another dictionary value as key

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-template

I'm facing an issue in one of my ansible templates regarding the lookup of a value inside a dictionary using the value from another dictionary as key.
This is part of hosts.yml:

```
brokers:
  vars:
    sym_nets_protocols:
      - {name: kback, protocol: plaintext, port: 9092}
      - {name: mgmt, protocol: plaintext, port: 9092}
      - {name: fwint, protocol: plaintext, port: 9092}
      - {name: planet, protocol: plaintext, port: 9092}
    inter.broker.net: kback
  hosts:
    br01:
      networks:
        - {name: mgmt, hostname: br01, ip: 10.10.10.16}
        - {name: kback, hostname: br01-kback.local, ip: 10.10.20.16}
        - {name: fwint, hostname: br01-fwint-local, ip: 10.10.30.16}
```

This is part of the template, the idea is to loop through the networks (networks dictionary) configured for the host, and lookup in sym_nets_protocols dictionary the value of the port; this makes sense because I can have multiple protocols on the same network (i.e. name: mgmt_ssl, protocol: ssl, port: 9093).

```
advertised.listeners={% for net in hostvars[inventory_hostname]['networks'] %}{% if loop.index > 1%},{% endif %} {{net.name}}://{{net.hostname}}:{{sym_nets_protocols[net]['port']}}  {% endfor %}
```

This is the launching task:

```
- name: broker config
  template:
    src: server.properties.j2
    dest: "{{kafka.broker.configdir}}{{kafka.broker.configfile}}"
    mode: 0640
    owner: "{{kafka.broker.user}}"
    group: "{{kafka.broker.group}}"
  when: security_mode == "plaintext"
  notify:
    - restart kafka
```

The result is this error:

```
fatal: [br01]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: list object has no element {u'mgmt': [{u'hostname': u'br01'}, {u'ip': u'10.10.10.16'}]}"
```

This is the result I'd like to obtain

```
advertised.listeners=mgmt://br01:9092,kback://br01-kback.local:9092,fwint://br01-fwint-local:9092
```

As in my comment below I considered filters without finding out a solution.
This is the modified template:

```
advertised.listeners={% for net in hostvars[inventory_hostname]['networks'] %}{% if loop.index > 1%},{% endif %} {{net.name}}://{{net.hostname}}:{{sym_nets_protocols | sort(attribute='name') | selectattr("name", "equalto", net.name) | map(attribute='port')}}  {% endfor %}
```

And this is the resulting error:

```
fatal: [br01]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'dict object' has no attribute 'name'"
```

Not sure if I've done whatever it takes to make it working.

**Solved!**

Not sure fi this is the better solution but it works.
This is the template

```
advertised.listeners={% for net in hostvars[inventory_hostname]['networks'] %}{% if loop.index > 1%},{% endif %}{% for sym_net in sym_nets_protocols %}{% if sym_net.name == net.name %}{{net.name}}://{{net.hostname}}:{{sym_net.port}}{% endif %}{% endfor %}{% endfor %}
```

HTH somebody else

Comment: After reading the suggested post I've modified my template as follows:


advertised.listeners={% for net in hostvars[inventory_hostname]['networks'] %}{% if loop.index > 1%},{% endif %} {{net.name}}://{{net.hostname}}:{{sym_nets_protocols | sort(attribute='name') | selectattr("name", "equalto", net.name) | map(attribute='port')}}  {% endfor %}

But the result is another error:

fatal: [br01]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'dict object' has no attribute 'name'"

Any idea ?
Thanks

Comment: So you are doing something wrong, because this template works properly with the data posted above in the question, except for producing `<generator object do_map at 0x102da1af0>` instead of port (due to missing `first` filter) and spaces which you should delete. Also, `sort` is unnecessary, it does nothing.